# How do you access an HTML node using DOMDocument while retaining the inner HTML formatting?

Tags: php, domdocument

I am attempting to access the contents of a spreadsheet cell from Google Docs using DOMDocument in PHP.

I am able to access the node, but the contents are in plain text and missing the HTML formatting.

Here is the example link I am using, which has text that is bold, italic, and underlined.

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Klpic32Gb_TDblDZDJQOkDedFGuNHAokxUXqrCPDFWE/pubhtml
```

Below is the PHP code I am using:

```
    $url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Klpic32Gb_TDblDZDJQOkDedFGuNHAokxUXqrCPDFWE/pubhtml";

    $curl = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    $htmlData = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);

    $dom        = new \DOMDocument();
    $html       = $dom->loadHTML($htmlData); 
    $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;

    $tables     = $dom->getElementsByTagName('table');
    $rows       = $tables->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('tr');
    $cols       = $rows->item(1)->getElementsByTagName('td');  

    $rowHeaders = array();
    foreach ($cols as $i => $node) {

        if($i >= 0 ) $rowHeaders[] = $node->textContent;
    }

    foreach ($rows as $i => $row){
        if($i == 0 ) continue;
        $cols = $row->getElementsByTagName('td');
        $row = array();
        foreach ($cols as $j => $node) {
            $row[$rowHeaders[$j]] = $node->textContent;
        }
        $table[] = $row;
    }

    die(print_r($table));
```

My output is missing the inner HTML formatting:

```
[1] => Array
    (
        [Variable] => html_body
        [Data] => Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont use the textContent, try it:

```
foreach ($cols as $j => $node) {
    //$row[$rowHeaders[$j]] = $node->textContent;
    $innerHTML= '';
    $children = $node->childNodes;
    foreach ($children as $child) {
        $innerHTML .= $child->ownerDocument->saveXML( $child );
    }

    $row[$rowHeaders[$j]]= $innerHTML;
}
```

Comment: That's the ticket. Thank you.